# Crystal Report asking DB user name and password VS 2008

Tags: c#, vb.net, crystal-reports

I am using VS 2008 to develop an application. I am using Win 10(x64). I completed my development and everything is working just fine in my PC. But when I install the app in another machine crystal report is asking for User/Password every time. Even if I provide the correct username and password it says "Login Failed". I used SQL server native client to connect SQL tables in crystal reports.
Here is my code to load the report from the app.

```
        TableLogOnInfos crtableLogoninfos = new TableLogOnInfos();
        TableLogOnInfo crtableLogoninfo = new TableLogOnInfo();
        ConnectionInfo crConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
        Tables CrTables;

        //report object
        TupUp tp = new TupUp();

        crConnectionInfo.ServerName = "SOFTWARE\\sqlexpress";
        crConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = "DBname";
        crConnectionInfo.UserID = "uname";
        crConnectionInfo.Password = "pwd";

        CrTables = tp.Database.Tables;
        //CrTables = dea.Database.Tables;
        foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table CrTable in CrTables)
        {
            crtableLogoninfo = CrTable.LogOnInfo;
            crtableLogoninfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo;
            CrTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crtableLogoninfo);
        }

        //report viewer object
        RV RV = new RV();
        RV.crystalReportViewer1.DisplayGroupTree = false;
        tp.SetParameterValue("month", cmbMonth.Text);
        tp.SetParameterValue("year", cmbYear.Text);
        //tp.SetParameterValue("weekdays", weekdays);
        RV.crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = tp;
        RV.Refresh();
        RV.Show();
```

Please check if I am doing anything wrong in the above code.
Thanks in advance.[image: crystal report is asking password while loading report]

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. After installed SQL server native client 2005 version on the client machine, it starts working.

Thanks for the support.